Kibana Dashboards controls not interactive
I've couple of dashboards in my kibana space. For both the dashboards, using controls [optionlist], created a filter using one field in my index.
Also using links, formed horizontal menu / tabs to navigate between one another
What we observed is the values selected in my first dashboard is not reflecting in second dashboard controls
adding links options, tried enable and disable filters options

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
